# How to teach tefilla to small children in a way that makes it meaningful?

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, children-parenting, minor-katan-child, chinuch-education

Are there any schools of thought or practical methodologies for teaching tefilla to children under the age of 10 who are not native hebrew speakers in a way that is fun, engaging and makes the experience meaningful? If so what are the main recommendations? If not, please share any personal experiences which have been implemented successfully.

Comment: Similar, for a different age group: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9213/how-do-you-motivate-a-teen-who-has-no-interest-in-davening

Answer (score 5):

Songs have helped me, and the children like to catch on to the words. Also teaching them a little about what we are saying in the tefilla, in a way they will understand.